# Zend Framework adding route to restful controller

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework, routes, restful-url

Zend framework 1.7. I have a Restful controller with restfull routes.  http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest

```
$front     = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$restRoute = new Zend_Rest_Route($front, array(), array(
    'product' => array('ratings')
));
$front->getRouter()->addRoute('rest', $restRoute);
```

In `ratings` controller I have an `indexAction` that respond to `http get` request from url `product/ratings/`

Now in `ratings` controller I am adding a new action: `browseAction`. 
I want when digit the url `product/ratings/browse` respond the `indexAction`. 
Is possible to configure the router ?

Comment: Would be more helpful if you post the solution as an independent answer and choose it as the correct one. This will help other users looking for solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***SOLUTION***

```
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static ( 'product/ratings/browse', array (
        'controller' => 'ratings',
        'module' => 'product',
        'action' => 'index' 
) );
$front->getRouter ()->addRoute ( 'browse', $route );
```